# Multiple args in a java switch

Tags: java, char, switch-statement, arguments

I am expecting my input to be one of three groups of chars and need to decide what to do with it based on which group it falls in. I'm trying to figure out how to define a switch with multiple cases to do this. Here is what I have so far:

```
     while(in.hasNextChar())
      {
         char test = in.nextChar();
         List<Signal> out = new List<Signal>(0);
         switch(test)
         {
            case '1','0','x','X':
               out.add(fromString(test));
               break;
            case ' ','/t':
               break;
            default:
               throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal;
         }
      }
      return out;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong.  You need to take advantage of fall-through:

```
     switch(test) {
        case '1':
        case '0':
        case 'x':
        case 'X':
           out.add(fromString(test));
           break;
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
           break;
        default:
           throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal;
     }
```

A case is just a label, very similar to what you'd use with a `goto` (which is essentially what is happening behind the scenes).  It's not a statement, since it does nothing itself — it just names an address.  So if `test` is `'0'`, it can happily continue through the `'x'` and `'X'` cases to reach the actual statement code since there's not anything being done by those labels.  Only `break` "ends" a case.

You can actually insert code between cases even without a `break`:

```
switch(test) {
    case '1':
        System.out.println("This is printed by case '1'");
    case '0':
        System.out.println("This is printed by both case '1' and case '0'");
        break;
    case 'x':
    case 'X':
        System.out.println("This is only printed by the Xs");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why that should work, but I kinda see how it does. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @C.J.Coffey Your code just falls through to the first case that has a break.